How do identity providers like MS Entra ID work?
I'm looking to build a MS Teams tab application and want users to be able to authenticate into my app. I also don't want them to have to login every time they open the tab. I'm reading about MS Entra ID as an identity provider for OAuth and not entirely sure how it works. Specifically, it seems like the user would click "Login with Microsoft" and they may already be logged in or they may be prompted to login. Then they authenticate with microsoft and all of a sudden they are signed into my app? How does the MS Entra identity map to a user in my app? That's the main piece I am missing. My app only really requires an email to login as I send a tokenized link to users so maybe I don't need a mapping and just trust the email that the user is authenticating with? Any information or resources would be helpful! Thanks in advance!
